# Karnaugh Map: does maximal overlap always produce simplest boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-algebra, digital-circuits, karnaugh-map

Suppose I have a 4x4 Karnaugh map with a few cells that are *don't cares*, and there are two ways of producing 3 groups of 4 cells. One of these ways overlaps groupings more that the other. Is one way preferable over the other?
For example: [image]

Is **F = B'D' + AD' + CD'** simpler than **F = B'D' + AD' + A'C** (since the first one *reuses* more symbols), or would one say they are equally simple?

Comment: I think what you want to consider as "simpler" depends on the exact application, and this question probably doesn't have a definitive answer.

Comment: (Some cost models would account not only for the number of terms and primaries in each term, they would assign a cost to complementing. (I don't remember *reuse* as a bonus. Physically, it puts more load on a signal source - 2nd order malus?) Then, there are non-NF expressions: **C'D'(A'BC')'**.)